# Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz and the parallelogram equality

Tags: inner-products

Let $ V $ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with a norm $ \lVert\cdot\rVert$ that satisfies the parallelogram equality.

We define the inner product :
$$\langle x, y \rangle = \frac{1}{4} \left( \Vert x + y \Vert^2 - \Vert x - y \Vert^2\right).$$

and I need to prove that Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds with this inner product.

Here is my attempt:

$$|\langle x, y \rangle | = \frac{1}{4} \left| \Vert x + y \Vert^2 - \Vert x - y \Vert^2\right| \leq \frac{1}{4} \left( \Vert x + y \Vert^2 + \Vert x - y \Vert^2 \right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( 2 \left( \Vert x  \Vert^2 + \Vert y \Vert^2 \right) \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \Vert x  \Vert^2 + \Vert y \Vert^2  \right)  $$

Comment: Why not just use the usual CS proof from the axioms of an inner product? After all, I assume you've verified this "inner product" meets the axioms.

Answer (score 1):

There is no error in you calculations, but they wouldn't give you the result you're hoping for;

The inequality $$\frac{1}{4} \left| \Vert x + y \Vert^2 - \Vert x - y \Vert^2\right| \leq \frac{1}{4} \left( \Vert x + y \Vert^2 + \Vert x - y \Vert^2 \right) $$
is too weak for this manner.

*Hint*: Try separating the proof to $\langle x, y \rangle > 0 $ and $\langle x, y \rangle < 0 $, then try using the parallelogram equality + the norm's triangle inequality for each case.